# URL rewrite is working for http but not for https

Tags: https, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

We want to display content of "https" site under my "http" site  so, we are using IIS Rewrite module. (Same as CNAME)

We have created Inbound rules for same. However we are facing below error.

HTTP Error 502.3 - Bad Gateway

A connection with the server could not be established

If I use same rule in http site than it is working. Means We are able to display any http site content under my http site.

It is also working when we use "Redirect" action type but Here we want "Rewrite" action in rule because we do'not want to display another site Url

[Inbound Rules and further details are here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irpAf.png)

Comment: Have you checked any logs?

Comment: Can't get scarier than this. I'm having same problem but no SO answers so far.